# Customizing Login Page for Mobile SDK Hybrid Android App

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have a Hybrid Remote Android App built using Mobile SDK 3.1. It is configured to use a custom community login page (it is the only entry in `res/xml/servers.xml`).  It's working fine, except for two issues which don't exist in the iOS version of the app:

1. How do I suppress the header bar on the login page?  Shown here inside the red box:

[image]

2. Is there something about the login page that prevents me from loading cordova via `<script src="https://localhost/cordova.js"></script>`?  This works fine in the app, but the login page reports `connection refused` in the debugger.  How can I lift this restriction?  I need to use the splashscreen plugin (via javascript) once the login form is submitted to show the splash until the app is fully loaded.  Again, working fine on iOS.

I suspect that the Mobile SDK handles the login page with an Android WebView which is configured to show the titlebar and to disallow localhost access, but I'm just guessing here; I know little about native Android dev and have no idea how to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around in the [Salesforce MobileSDK for Android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android), it seems clear that both of my problems are due to design decisions within the Android version of the SDK.

For #1, suppressing the login page title bar probably could be accomplished by changing an `AndroidManifest.xml` (possibly the app's; certainly the MobileSDK plugin's), except that the code assumes that title bar is present, and causes a null pointer exception if it isn't.  So you'll have to modify the code.

First, update the plugin's manifest (`plugins/com.salesforce/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/AndroidManifest.xml`), and find:

```
    <!-- Login activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SalesforceSDK.ActionBarTheme" />
```

and change `android:theme` to `"@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`.  Next, open:

```
app/plugins/com.salesforce/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/ui/LoginActivity.java
```

find the `onCreate` and comment out these two lines:

```
    // We'll show progress in the window title bar
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Finally, find method `loadingLoginPage`, and replace `ab.setTitle(loginUrl);` with:

```
    if (ab!=null) {
        ab.setTitle(loginUrl);
    }
```

You'll need to rebuild the sdk; `cordova` doesn't seem to do so for me.  I use the following:

```
cd platforms/android
ant debug  # or ant release for release version
```

For #2, serving files from localhost inside the login view, it looks like the app's main web view is an instance of `SalesforceDroidGapActivity` which has support for localhost urls (via `SalesforceIceCreamWebViewClient`), but the login page is an instance of `LoginActivity` which extends `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, and has no localhost support.  Dropping in one for the other doesn't look practical either.  I think the login view should have access to `file://` urls, but I'm not sure if the cordova js file and plugins would be accessible via such a file url; I'll update this post if I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to add in the Manifest file the following:

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
     android:theme="@style/SalesforceTheme.NoActionBar"
     tools:replace="android:theme"
  />
```