# Remove Header from salesforce sdk in android

Tags: android, salesforcesdk

I have tried the way [Customizing Login Page for Mobile SDK Hybrid Android App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68744/customizing-login-page-for-mobile-sdk-hybrid-android-app) but I am not able to remove the header for android. I was able to remove the header for ios. Looking for solution as per the latest sdk.